# can private methods be over ridden in child class

Tags: php, oop, overriding

This is an example where a child class method can override the parent method if the access type of the method is public
EX:

```
class Foo {

  public function fun1() {
    echo "Hello World";
  }

  public function callMe(){
    $this->fun1();
  }
}


class Bar extends Foo {

  public function fun1(){
    echo "check this out";
  }
}

$bar = new Bar();
$bar->callMe(); //this would print "check this out"
```

But if the `fun1` is given `private` access in the parent class `Foo` then the method no longer gets over ridden.

Ex:

```
class Foo {

  private function fun1() {
    echo "hello world";
  }

  public function callMe(){
    $this->fun1();
  }
}
```

In this case the output will be `hello world`.
I want to know, if it is possible to override the method `fun1` by an extended class even with an access type of `private`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have no idea about PHP but per OOP concept **NO** since a method with access modifier `private` is though present but not overridable or accessible to child class. If you want to override it to child class then try changing the access modifier to either `public` or `protected`

Comment: Whoever downvoted, are you not able to follow the answer? Or do you see anything missing in answer?